# meaning of (number) & (-number)

Tags: c++, c

What is the meaning of  `(number) & (-number)`? I have searched it but was unable to find the meaning

I want to use `i & (-i)` in for loop like:

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i += i & (-i))
```

Comment: A bitwise and with the negation.

Comment: Why do you want to use it, if you do not know what it means?

Comment: You want to use it in a loop but you don't know what it does?

Comment: I hope that `i` is declared with an unsigned type.

Comment: i was solving a question but was unable to do it. i had a look at solution and this was the only thing i couldnot understand.my approach was a timeout so i think it is used to optmize code

Comment: The `i=0` initialiser does make the loop infinite since `i&(-i)` is also 0. What's does the content of the loop do?

Comment: @SKIZZ: I dont think 'i&(-i)' is aalways 0.  With twos-compliment, 1&-1 results in 1.

Comment: @MooingDuck: When `i=0` as it is in the code that is given, `i&(-i)` is also 0 and so the loop is infinite provided the body does not change `i`. You're right that `i&(-i) != 0` for `i > 0`, but `i` is zero in the question.

Comment: With `i = 0;`, this is an infinite loop as others commented. Let's assume that's **NOT** the intention. Let's try `for (i = 1; i <= n; i += i & -i) ;`. First iteration, i is 1, -i is -1, i&-i is 0x01 & 0xff is 1 (assume signed byte) so i += i&-i gives i is 2. Second iteration, i is 2, -i is -2, i & -i is 0x02 & 0xfe is 2, so i += i & -i gives i is 4 ('is' means 'equals'). Then 8,16,32,... till i > n. OP says 'solving a question' so might be some CompSci exam testing binary logic and arithmetic. Maybe the `i=0` was correct and this was a find the bug exam. Still need binary skills to prove it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming 2's complement (or that `i` is unsigned), `-i` is equal to `~i+1`.

`i & (~i + 1)` is a trick to extract the lowest set bit of `i`.

It works because what +1 actually does is to set the lowest clear bit, and clear all bits lower than that. So the only bit that is set in both `i` and `~i+1` is the lowest set bit from `i` (that is, the lowest clear bit in `~i`). The bits lower than that are clear in `~i+1`, and the bits higher than that are non-equal between `i` and `~i`.

Using it in a loop seems odd unless the loop body modifies `i`, because `i = i & (-i)` is an idempotent operation: doing it twice gives the same result again.

[Edit: in a comment elsewhere you point out that the code is actually `i += i & (-i)`. So what that does for non-zero `i` is to clear the lowest group of set bits of `i`, and set the next clear bit above that, for example 101100 -> 110000. For `i` with no clear bit higher than the lowest set bit (including `i = 0`), it sets `i` to 0. So if it weren't for the fact that `i` starts at `0`, each loop would increase `i` by *at least* twice as much as the previous loop, sometimes more, until eventually it exceeds `n` and breaks or goes to `0` and loops forever.

It would normally be inexcusable to write code like this without a comment, but depending on the domain of the problem *maybe* this is an "obvious" sequence of values to loop over.]

Comment: it seems that he is going to change the value of i in the loops body..i think `i=i&(-i)` is for keeping it `positive`

Comment: @Anirudha: if it is intended to keep it positive then it doesn't work for the case where only the topmost bit is set. But anyway, the questioner says in a comment that `i` is unsigned.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that negative values are using two's complement. Then `-number` can be calculated as `(~number)+1`, flip the bits and add 1.

For example if `number = 92`. Then this is what it would look like in binary:

```
number               0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 1100
~number              1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1010 0011
(~number) + 1        1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1010 0100
-number              1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1010 0100
(number) & (-number) 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100
```

You can see from the example above that `(number) & (-number)` gives you the least bit.

You can see the code run online on IDE One: http://ideone.com/WzpxSD

Here is some C code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void printIntBits(int num);
void printExpression(char *text, int value);

int main() {
  int number = 92;

  printExpression("number", number);
  printExpression("~number", ~number);
  printExpression("(~number) + 1", (~number) + 1);
  printExpression("-number", -number);
  printExpression("(number) & (-number)", (number) & (-number));

  return 0;
}

void printExpression(char *text, int value) {
  printf("%-20s", text);
  printIntBits(value);
  printf("\n");
}

void printIntBits(int num) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int mask = (0xF0000000 >> (i * 4));
        int portion = (num & mask) >> ((7 - i) * 4);
      cout << " " << std::bitset<4>(portion);
    }
}
```

Also here is a version in C# .NET: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ai7Eq6

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd just take a moment to show how this works. This code gives you the lowest set bit's value:

```
int i = 0xFFFFFFFF; //Last byte is 1111(base 2), -1(base 10)
int j = -i;         //-(-1) == 1
int k = i&j;        //   1111(2) = -1(10) 
                    // & 0001(2) =  1(10)
                    // ------------------
                    //   0001(2) = 1(10). So the lowest set bit here is the 1's bit


int i = 0x80;       //Last 2 bytes are 1000 0000(base 2), 128(base 10)
int j = -i;         //-(128) == -128
int k = i&j;        //   ...0000 0000 1000 0000(2) =  128(10) 
                    // & ...1111 1111 1000 0000(2) = -128(10)
                    // ---------------------------
                    //   1000 0000(2) = 128(10). So the lowest set bit here is the 128's bit

int i = 0xFFFFFFC0; //Last 2 bytes are 1100 0000(base 2), -64(base 10)
int j = -i;         //-(-64) == 64
int k = i&j;        //   1100 0000(2) = -64(10) 
                    // & 0100 0000(2) =  64(10)
                    // ------------------
                    //   0100 0000(2) = 64(10). So the lowest set bit here is the 64's bit
```

It works the same for unsigned values, the result is always the lowest set bit's value.

Given your loop:

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i=i&(-i))
```

There are no bits set (`i=0`) so you're going to get back a 0 for the increment step of this operation. So this loop will go on forever unless `n=0` or `i` is modified.

Comment: it is  i += i & (-i);somebody edited my post and did  i = i & (-i);

Comment: @aseem - OK, but it doesn't matter unless `i` is changed inside the loop(which is probably why it was edited). `i=0`, therefore `i&(-i)=0`, so `i+=i&(-i)` is just going to add 0 in so `i=0+0&(-0)` and it stays 0.

Answer (score 2):

The operation `i & -i` is used for isolating the least significant non-zero bit of the corresponding integer.

- In binary notation `num` can be represented as `a1b`, where `a` represents binary digits before the last bit and `b` represents zeroes after the last bit.
- `-num` is equal to `(a1b)¯ + 1 = a¯0b¯ + 1`. `b` consists of all zeroes, so `b¯` consists of all ones.

  - `-num = (a1b)¯ + 1` => `a¯0b¯ + 1` => `a¯0(0…0)¯ + 1` => `¯0(1…1) + 1` => `a¯1(0…0)` => `a¯1b`
- Now, `num & -num` => `a1b & a¯1b` => `(0..0)1(0..0)`

For e.g. if i = 5

```
| iteration | i | last bit position | i & -i|
|-------- |--------|-------- |-----|
| 1    | 5 = 101     | 0 | 1 (2^0)|
| 2    | 6 = 110     | 1 | 2 (2^1)|
| 3    | 8 = 1000    | 3 | 8 (2^3)|
| 4    | 16 = 10000  | 4 | 16 (2^4)|
| 5    | 32 = 100000 | 5 | 32 (2^5)|
```

This operation in mainly used in **Binary Indexed Trees** to move up and down the tree

PS: For some reason stackoverflow is treating table as code :(