# Odd bit operator in the increment statement of a for loop

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, bit-manipulation

Given this for loop:

```
for(++i; i < MAX_N; i += i & -i)
```

what is it supposed to mean? What does the statement `i += i & -i` accomplish?

Comment: @user3670482 this is a simple  snap of a code all the variables are well defined in the whole code

Comment: What is the initial value of i? I wonder why the programmer did not simply use `i <<= 1`.

Comment: @SalmanA Because `i <<= 1` is not what programmer wants?

Comment: What is the initial value of `i`?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772669/why-is-i-i-i-1-equivalent-to-i-i

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This loop is often observed in binary indexed tree (or BIT) implementation which is useful to update range or point and query range or point in logarithmic time. This loop helps to choose the appropriate bucket based on the set bit in the index. For more details, please consider to read about BIT from some other source. In below post I will show how does this loop help to find the appropriate buckets based on the least significant set bits.

**2s complementary signed system (when i is signed)**
`i & -i` is a bit hack to quickly find the number that should be added to given number to make its trailing bit 0(that's why performance of BIT is logarithmic). When you negate a number in ***[2s complementary system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)***, you will get a number with bits in inverse pattern added `1` to it. When you add `1`, all the less significant bits would start inverting as long as they are `1` (were `0` in original number). First `0` bit encountered (`1` in original i) would become `1`.

When you and both `i` and `-i`, only that bit (least significant `1` bit) would remain set and all lesser significant (right) bits would be `zero` and more significant bits would be `inverse` of original number.

Anding would generate a power of `2` number that when added to number `i` would clear the least significant set bit. (as per the requirement of [BIT](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10538/bit-what-is-the-intuition-behind-a-binary-indexed-tree-and-how-was-it-thought-a))

For example:

```
i = 28
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                      *
-i
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  I   I   I   I   I   S   Z   Z
Z = Zero
I = Inverted
S = Same
* = least significant set bit

i & -i
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

Adding
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                      x
x = cleared now
```

**Unsigned (when i is unsigned)**
It will work even for `1s complementary system` or any other representation system as long as `i` is `unsigned` for the following reason:

`-i` will take value of **2<sup>sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BITS</sup> - i**. So all the bits right to the least significant set bit would remain `zero`, least significant bit would also remain zero, but all the bits after that would be inverted because of the carry bits.

For example:

```
i = 28
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                           *
-i
   0   1   1   1   1   1   <--- Carry bits
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   - | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   ----------------------------------------
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
       I   I   I   I   I   S   Z   Z
Z = Zero
I = Inverted
S = Same
* = least significant set bit

i & -i
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

Adding
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                      x
x = cleared now
```

**Implementation without bithack**

You can also use `i += (int)(1U << __builtin_ctz((unsigned)i))` on gcc.

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/vMSsX9)

A non obfuscated version for the same would be:

```
/* Finds smallest power of 2 that can reset the least significant set bit on adding */
int convert(int i) /* I purposely kept i signed as this works for both */
{
    int t = 1, d;
    for(; /* ever */ ;) {
        d = t + i; /* Try this value of t */
        if(d & t) t *= 2;  /* bit at mask t was 0, try next */
        else break; /* Found */
    }
    return t;
}
```

**EDIT**
Adding from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818978/meaning-of-number-number):

> Assuming 2's complement (or that i is unsigned), -i is equal to ~i+1.
>
> i & (~i + 1) is a trick to extract the lowest set bit of i.
>
> It works because what +1 actually does is to set the lowest clear bit,
>   and clear all bits lower than that. So the only bit that is set in
>   both i and ~i+1 is the lowest set bit from i (that is, the lowest
>   clear bit in ~i). The bits lower than that are clear in ~i+1, and the
>   bits higher than that are non-equal between i and ~i.

Comment: `2s complementary system` It's worth pointing out that C++ doesn't mandate 2s complement so it may well have different effects on different platforms. Either way this code should be banished back to the 80s from whence it came.

Comment: Many bithacks are dependent on representation (2s, IEEE floating point etc.) One should use these at his own rist. On 1s system you can use something like `if(i) (i & (-i) + 1)`

Comment: Does it mean that the program loops over i = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16...?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes if initially i was 0. No if it was not. For example if i was 36, it will loop as `37 -> 38 -> 40 -> 48 -> 64 -> 128 -> 256 -> 512 ...`

Comment: @user657267 well what else are you going to do, write it as a loop like the last code block? Don't be surprised if your coworkers punch you for making it needlessly slow and not even especially clear.

Comment: Using `__builtin_ctz` that way is actually not equivalent to the original because it's undefined on zero. Using `unsigned` will make it work for imaginary non-two's-complement machines.

Comment: @harold Looking at the usage of this code, it appears to be used in BIT. Quering for index 0 will test if from 1 : `for(++i; i < MAX_N; i += i & -i)`. So `__builtin_ctz ` is safe. For any other usage, I would prefer checking explicitly for zero.

Comment: @GyaptiJain ok good point

Comment: C and C++ do not mandate 2's complement for signed numbers, but it *does* mandate modulo arithmetic for unsigned and that's the same as 2's complement. So the operation is guaranteed to work in unsigned type!

Comment: what's an use case for this ? I mean what is the first algorithm from the top of your head that takes advantage from this ?

Comment: @user2485710 BIT or binary indexed trees

Comment: you mean like an huffman one ?

Comment: @user2485710 You can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree)